# Simple Multi-column combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to do a simple multi-column combobox and do it in such a way that I can bind another control to it.

I have made the combobox work in a few diffeent ways, at the moment I am using this [one](http://netindonesia.net/blogs/mahara/archive/2008/12/10/a-simple-multicolumn-combo-box-in-wpf.aspx) but every tutorial I seem to find skips how to parse the values of the selections.

are there any good third party controls that do this?  or a good tutorial to make one?

thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure about what you mean by "parse the values of the selections". Have you tried using an `IValueConverter`?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43074/WPF-Custom-ComboBox) seems like a good tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combobox from article you used looks alright. There is no need for parsing anything. In your combobox you can access the `SelectedItem` property to grab currently selected item.

Comment: yes, but how exactly do i get the values?  sending it tostring() just gives me "Comboboxtesting.mainwindow+person"

Comment: You have to cast the object into a `person` object:
string name = ((Person)myComboBox.SelectedItem).Name

Comment: Nevermind!  I was going to the wrong combobox.  thanks!